# Binding to dictionary includes extra "Index" key

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.Net MVC 4 and binding a form with a list of multiple repeated fields to a dictionary, using the method explained on Phil Haack's blog: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Here's a portion of my markup:

```
<tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="RowName[0]" /></td>
              <td><input type="hidden" name="SlotDefs.Index" value="Mon|0" /><input type="hidden" name="SlotDefs[Mon|0].Sequence" value="0" /><input type="number" name="SlotDefs[Mon|0].Count" /></td>
              <td><input type="hidden" name="SlotDefs.Index" value="Tue|0" /><input type="hidden" name="SlotDefs[Tue|0].Sequence" value="1" /><input type="number" name="SlotDefs[Tue|0].Count" /></td>
              <td><input type="hidden" name="SlotDefs.Index" value="Wed|0" /><input type="hidden" name="SlotDefs[Wed|0].Sequence" value="2" /><input type="number" name="SlotDefs[Wed|0].Count" /></td>
              <td><input type="hidden" name="SlotDefs.Index" value="Thu|0" /><input type="hidden" name="SlotDefs[Thu|0].Sequence" value="3" /><input type="number" name="SlotDefs[Thu|0].Count" /></td>
              <td><input type="hidden" name="SlotDefs.Index" value="Fri|0" /><input type="hidden" name="SlotDefs[Fri|0].Sequence" value="4" /><input type="number" name="SlotDefs[Fri|0].Count" /></td>
            </tr>
...
```

In all there are 20 `SlotDefs` in the form, and they do get bound to a `IDictionary<string, SlotDefinitionModel>` within the model that the controller receives.  However, there's also an extra element in the collection, with key "Index" and a null value.  Why is that there?  I have to filter it out before processing the rest of the data.  Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Are you using `<input type="submit">` by chance?  Just curious.

Comment: I'm using `<button type="submit">`.

Answer (score 1):

I never tried binding to an IDictionary object before, but I believe that this "Index" key came from

```
<input type="hidden" name="SlotDefs.Index" value="Mon|0" />
```

You can remove this field and the binding will occur like you expect.

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="RowName[0]" /></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="SlotDefs[Mon|0].Sequence" value="0" /><input  type="number" name="SlotDefs[Mon|0].Count" /></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="SlotDefs[Tue|0].Sequence" value="1" /><input  type="number" name="SlotDefs[Tue|0].Count" /></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="SlotDefs[Wed|0].Sequence" value="2" /><input type="number" name="SlotDefs[Wed|0].Count" /></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="SlotDefs[Thu|0].Sequence" value="3" /><input type="number" name="SlotDefs[Thu|0].Count" /></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="SlotDefs[Fri|0].Sequence" value="4" /><input type="number" name="SlotDefs[Fri|0].Count" /></td>
    </tr>
```

...